# A simple conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, self-learning, conditional-probability

Assume that two fair dice are rolled one at a time. Given that the sum of the two numbers that occured was at least $7$, compute the probability that it was equal to $7$.

I tried computing the probability as follows:

$$P \left( X+Y=7| X+Y \geq 7 \right)=\frac{P \left(X+Y=7 \right)}{P \left(X+Y \geq 7 \right)}$$

And then I examined all different pairs whose sum is $7$ and then those whose sum is greater or equal to $7$. I am getting $3/12$ but the right answer is $6/21$. Could you please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that you can get $6$ in the first dice and $1$ in the second one, or $1$ in the first dice and $6$ in the second one.

Comment: @mfl Yep, I have accounted for that.

Comment: $7$, $6$ ways; $8$, $5$ ways; $9$, $4$ ways. Then $3$, $2$, $1$, sum $6+5+4+3+2+1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you but why is $8$, 5 ways? Should we not count the fact that $(4,4)$ can occur in two ways?

Comment: Record the results as $(a,b)$, where $a$ is the number on the green and $b$ the number on the red. All ordered pairs are **equally likely** and there is **only one** $(4,4)$. If you apply your reasoning to tossing a dime and a quarter, you will get probability of $2$ heads $2/4$, probability of $2$ tails $2/4$, probability of mixed $2/4$, impossible total of $3/2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Quite right. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. So that was the source of your problem, an extra $1$ for each of  $8,10,12$, giving $6/(21+3)$ instead of $6/21$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of possible outcomes when rolling two fair dice is $6^2=36$.

Examining the denominator of your conditional probability, it is easier to deal with the case when the sum of the two dice ($X+Y$) is less than $7$, and subtract this result from $36$.

Now, there are $5$ outcomes (pairs ($5$,$1$),($4$,$2$),($3$,$3$),($2$,$4$),($1$,$5$)) for the sum to be $6$, $4$ outcomes for the sum to be $5$, and so on, until the minimum value (which is $2$, where each die shows a $1$).

So the total number of outcomes where $X+Y < 7$ is $5+4+3+2+1=15$.

As a result the total number of outcomes where $X+Y \geq 7$ is $36-15=21$, leading to
$$P(X+Y\geq 7)=\frac{21}{36}$$

Next, we count the number of total outcomes where $X+Y=7$, which is $6$ (($6$,$1$)($5$,$2$),($4$,$3$),($3$,$4$),($2$,$5$),($1$,$6$)), so that
$$P(X+Y=7)=\frac{6}{36}$$

We thus obtain
$$P(X+Y=7|X+Y\geq 7)=\frac{(P(X+Y=7) \cap (X+Y\geq7))}{P(X+Y\geq7)}=\frac{P(X+Y=7)}{P(X+Y\geq7)}\\=\frac{6}{36}\times\frac{36}{21}=\frac{6}{21}=\frac{2}{7}$$

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I had counted twice tied pairs such as your $(3,3)$. I mistakingly thought that it can occur in two ways.

Answer (score 2):

$P(X+Y=7) = 1/6$

By Symmetry

$P(X+Y>7) = P(X+Y<7) = (1 - 1/6)/2$

$P(X+Y>=7) = P(X+Y>7)+P(X+Y=7) = 5/12 + 1/6$

$P( X+Y=7| X+Y >= 7) = \frac{1/6}{5/12+1/6} = 6/21$

Comment: I think your third line is wrong.

Comment: Forgot the 1/6. It was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You're mistake lies in the equation you used for calculating. The LHS is not equal to the RHS.
I believe the best approach to calculating the conditional probability in this instance would be to use Bayes' Theorem.

Theorem: Pr[A|B] = (Pr[B|A]*Pr[A])/Pr[B]

So here, Pr[B|A]=Pr[X+Y>=7|X+Y=7]=1,

Pr[A]=Pr[X+Y=7]=6/36

Pr[B]=Pr[X+Y>=7]=21/36

Hence, answer is 6/21.

Comment: The equation is correct. It is the fact that I have double-counted outcomes such as $(3,3)$ that messed up the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

How many ordered pairs of rolls give you a number over $6$? How many give you exactly  $7$?

Comment: 6 pairs give me exactly 7, namely $(1,6),(2,5),(3,4)$ Continuing like this I am getting 24 pairs over 6. Thus $6/24=3/12$